# redirecting after logout

Tags: php, redirect

I'm having problem redirecting the user to the frontpage when he logs out. I have a switch case statement and the one handling logout looks like this:

```
    case 'logout':
    offline($_SESSION['user_id']);
    session_destroy();
    include_once 'index.php';
    break;
```

I thought that including index.php would redirect the user to the frontpage since that's what should happen when the session. but the page is just blank and the url is localhost/web//?a=logout.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, OP! I have updated my answer, even though you didn't ask for it. So, check it this again

put `header('Location: http://site.com/index.php');`

Make your code like this:

```
case 'logout':
    offline($_SESSION['user_id']);
    session_destroy();
  header('Location: http://site.com/index.php');
   exit();
    break;
```

Comment: I guess you mean `header('Location: index.php');` and you should call `exit();` afterwards.

Comment: This answer still is wrong. Not only isn't the `L` of Location lowercase, but is also should be a absolute (a.k.a. full URL).

Comment: This answer is incorrect. RFC 2616 requires that `Location` headers specify an **absolute URI**; `index.php` is a **relative URI**. While a browser may fix it in some cases, it's a violation of the HTTP specification and should not be relied upon. Quoting specifically from [RFC 2616 Section 14.30](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30): *The field value consists of a single absolute URI.*

Comment: @rdlowrey what if the file is in the same directory? Why should one use absolute urls instead?

Comment: I don't care if Tim Berners-Lee sent you a hand-written Christmas card giving you permission to use a relative URI, you should *always* use absolute URIs.